# Bootstrap Date picker not showing dates after response

Tags: jquery, spring, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form where two text fields filled with date. Recently, i upgraded to bootstarp and i used bootstarp date-picker for this two text box fields. Before this, I had jquery Date picker for these fields. i use Spring MVC for submitting this form. So, when i submit the form before integration of bootstrap, the return model and jsp will show user entered date in those fields. These fields became empty after upgrading to bootstrap. Any idea on why this with bootstrap!

Thanks for the help.

Comment: We have to see your code ( html and js ) in order to help you out. Also check for errors in the error console of your browser.

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out as i missed form tag in front the input type.

Comment: glad you find the solution!